# Questions about lookup speed for different data structures (lists, tuples, sets and dictionaries)

Tags: python-3.x, lookup

I tried timing `if x in` with timeit to test the difference between lists, tuples, dictionaries and sets.

Input:

```
arr = [45,42,2,18,23,1170,12,41,40,9,47,24,33,28,10,32,29,17,46,11,759,37,6,26,21,49,31,14,19,8,13,7,27,22,3,36,34,38,39,30,43,15,4,16,35,25,20,44,5,48]
d = {x: None for x in arr}
s = set(arr)
t = tuple(arr)

print(timeit.timeit(stmt="1170 in arr",globals = globals()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="1170 in d",globals = globals()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="1170 in s",globals = globals()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="1170 in t",globals = globals()))
```

output:

```
0.04749280004762113
0.03289399994537234
0.02820739999879152
0.05428230005782098
```

I read online that lookups for sets and dictionaries were O(1), while lookups for tuples and lists were O(n) or at best O(log n).

**My questions are:**

- How come sets/dictionaries are O(1) while lists/tuples are O(n)?
- How come sets are faster than dictionaries, when both are O(1)?
- How come tuples are slower than lists, when both are O(n)?

**Edit:**
If I lookup an item that is not in the data structure, like 9999 (as suggested by Andrej Kesely) I observe dictionaries being consistently faster than sets, while lists are still slightly faster than tuples.

output:

```
0.2764877999434248
0.0286063000094146
0.0490725999698043
0.3088887999765575
```

Comment: instead `1170` try to change the value to `9999` and observe the results.

Comment: Using ```9999```` makes dictionaries consistently faster than sets, but the difference between lists and tuples remain. This didn't make me any less confused about how these data structures work.

Comment: The way tuples work is some piece of data is known to be at a certain index. The idea of rooting through all the fields of a tuple looking for something seems questionable.

Comment: I don't think this is actually a Python question, you're asking about general data structures. Might answer from home later

Comment: @NathanHughes that is a reasonable comment and I will add that I have never iterated through a tuple, looking for a specific item, I just don't understand why it would be any slower than a list.

Comment: @TimothyH I added the tag Python, because I thought the relative lookup speeds for data structures might also depend on the language? Sets being faster than dictionaries for items in the data structure, but dictionaries being faster than sets for items not in the data structure, could be a language thing? I am no CS, so the tag Python might be irrelevant.

Comment: Gotcha... Honestly the language default can explain it and in simple terms, that is language but really the question isn't about that.  Answer incoming

Comment: @JFK: Differences between `tuple` and `list` are going to come down to specific micro-optimizations; if anything, `tuple`s would have a *very* slight advantage on speed (because the storage for the `tuple` is allocated in a single block, while `list`s have an object header and a separately allocated array of pointers to the real data). Those optimizations have changed a *lot* in recent versions of CPython, can you provide the exact version of Python you're running (I assume CPython, but is it 3.12, 3.11, etc., is it 32 or 64 bit, which OS, etc.)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes it is CPython, and the version is 3.12.2, it is 64 bit and OS is win10. I also expected tuples to be faster than lists, but I found the opposite to be true when testing it.

Comment: @JFK: Having checked the source code, `tuple`s should definitely be faster in theory. My only guess is that your code was built with PGO that decided to optimize the `list` path more than the `tuple`. It's a trivial difference (if I'm reading it right, the difference is at a fraction of a nanosecond per operation, and nothing Python does takes less than a few nanoseconds to run, so a fraction of a nanosecond is meaningless). On my own machine, 3.11.8, Alpine Linux running under WSLv2, same tests, `tuple` wins by 5-10%, so there's no useful explanation to give here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger timeit repeats the statement 10^6 times, so per operation is X * 10^-6 seconds with X being 0.047 for lists and 0.054 for tuples (with item in data structure). So difference per operation is about 7 nanoseconds. From the comments and answers on this post, I think I can conclude that the differences between sets/dictionaries and tuples/lists is due to different optimizations? It isn't that sets are inherently faster/slower than dictionaries or lists inherently slower/faster than tuples.

Comment: Yep. That's a reasonable conclusion to draw. I was comparing on the "not found", and messed up the math a bit, but yeah, that's about right. I'm frankly confused by `list`s winning on your system (on top of not being contiguous memory, they have to recheck their own length after each comparison, in case the length of the `list` changed between checks, a problem `tuple`s can avoid), but it's a trivial win. And I expect `set`s and `dict`s to trade-off on wins depending on the context (they're optimized for different use cases), so that's no surprise at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah I can follow your reasoning (and that of others) that tuples should, if anything, be slightly faster than lists. But I am satisfied knowing that these differences aren't fundamental or related to the data structures, but more so optimization. I appreciate your time, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O notation is used to represent in general, how efficient an algorithm is. It does so purely from a theoretical perspective and in limits to operation flow, not actual time. It is possible, though unlikely for an optimized version of an algorithm to have worse rating using Big-O due to problem specific things. O(1) means the operation will always take a constant time. O(n) means the operation will take an amount of time correlating directly to the number of elements being operated over. O(log n) is generally the fastest algorithm achievable.

Dictionaries are constant time (O(1)) because they essentially give a function for getting an integer from an input value, and that integer is used basically as an array index. So a huge memory area is taken up, but if you generate the index from this hash function using a key, then the result is given immediately.

Set's, I've not looked into for sure, but thinking about them... Probably they are just dictionaries such that the values are boolean initialized to false or something.

Searching linearly through a list or tuple is O(n) because you go from left to right. Access into a list or tuple also is O(n), however access into an array when you know it's index is O(1) (notably, not all lists are the same but this is for an unoptimized linked list).

Everything I know off hand says tuple *should* be faster unless your functionally modifying it instead of mutating a list? I don't understand this, if someone comments then I'll update.

Comment: " O(log n) is generally the fastest algorithm achievable." ... no? It is not faster than O(1)

Comment: `set`s are not just `dict`s with dummy values (they were *very* early on when first introduced, but they've diverged dramatically since). That said, they're both still hash-based, so the big-O for both is similar, but the designs differ enough that you'll see meaningful differences in different scenarios.

Comment: "Access into a list or tuple also is O(n), " no, accessing an item is constant time for both lists and tuples. It isnt' clear what you mean by "access" here bthough, but in general, both have random access

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Constant time is fastest, I used that phrasing because generally you can't get it down to constant time when you have to process variable length indeterminate elements, that is technically correct, but I didn't feel quite right going to that length. Pure linked list implementations such as those Python *used* (close, not exact) to have access and search time (unordered) O(n), arrays and array-lists have constant or semi-constant access time, search still takes more time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks... I'd be able to read more on that from the Python docs?

Comment: @TimothyH: It's mostly hidden in the implementation, though some of the recent What's New docs do go into the specific optimizations made (a big one was in 3.6, when they introduced insertion-ordered `dict`s by default, no need for `OrderedDict` unless you needed the additional *re*ordering features or order-sensitive comparisons of `OrderedDict`, but `set` and `dict` had been diverging long before then). To be clear, Python doesn't do plain linked lists for the builtins. `collections.deque` is the closest you get (even then, it's linked lists of blocks of elements, not a link per element).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for all the info, I was aware of that for the ordereddict from 3.6 and that the list's weren't plain linked list, but they also aren't plain arraylists, I had wanted to generalize my answer to be applied anywhere, you think I should add a section explaining those details unique to Python?

Comment: @TimothyH: `list` is pure dynamically expanded array list, nothing else. Essentially identical to a `std::vector` in C++, `ArrayList` in Java, etc.

Comment: Thanks... *That* is news to me... Nitpicking differences between vectors and arraylists but essentially the same yeah. Thank you very much... The array list just holds a pointer to all the python objects and those objects have all their type info (this is something I ought to look up on my own instead of asking but meh, I'm bad)?

Comment: @TimothyH: Yep, Python's `list` is roughly equivalent to a `std::vector` of `std::shared_ptr` to arbitrary objects, whose types are linked from within each object. This does mean that, unlike C++ where `vector` growth can be an unpredictable performance menace (dependent on the cost of moving/copying the held objects), `list` growth in Python is pretty cheap (even if `realloc` can't operate in-place, it's a simple `memcpy`-like operation to copy over the pointers from old storage to new storage).